# Need SQL query which accepts EMPTY values in IN 'clause'

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I am newbie to the SQL. 
I have a **requirement** where users might select any values from any of the 3 'multiple list' dropdown box. There might be cases where user can completely ignore any of the dropdown box out of the 3.

So i need a query which can handle that.
The equivalent select query with values looks like this.

```
SELECT * FROM TABLE WHERE 
description1 LIKE '%SHK ABS%' OR 
description2 LIKE '%SHK ABS%' OR 
description3 LIKE '%SHK ABS%' OR 
description4 LIKE '%SHK ABS%' and 
**Year** in ('2017','2016') and 
**Program** in ('CDPGM');
```

**Problem:**
I tried a lot but not able to write a query which accepts empty values in 'IN' clause. 
**Example:** If user dint select any year and program, then empty values will be passed. Basically the query should act like it will ignore that columns in where clause.

Any idea how to achieve this ?

Comment: Why such a tag spam? Is your DBMS really MySQL, SQLServer or Oracle? Answer may depend on exact DBMS you have.

Comment: I suggest to rather build your query differently when values are empty. I bet that's much less hassle.

Comment: IN doesn't allow empty values. By if it did, WHERE Year IN () would be equivalent to WHERE 1 = 0, that is: always false. I guess this is not what you want, If the user ignores the checked list, I guess you don't want to filter by the corresponding column, so don't include the column in the WHERE clause

Comment: What is your DB? SQL?

Comment: Actually i have a Toplink workbench connected to MS SQL 2008 r2 which my project suggests to use and we are not authorized to use other tools. I am not able to customize it in the workbench and so i have only option to use a static expression query :(

Comment: As an aside, you might want to enclose the LIKE conditions in brackets, as in `… WHERE (description1 LIKE '%SHK ABS%' OR description2 LIKE '%SHK ABS%' OR description3 LIKE '%SHK ABS%' OR description4 LIKE '%SHK ABS%') and …`. Otherwise the Year and Program conditions will be disregarded for description1, description2 and description3.

Answer (score 1):

As per I understand there can be three type of empty values according to your case: **NULL**, **Blank** and **Space(s)**.

The `in` clause to match those will look like:

```
SELECT * FROM table_name WHRE col_name in (null, '', <your other values>);
```

I have tested it in MySQL 5.6(latest version). For other versions/DBMSs you may need to use `trim` function:

```
SELECT * FROM table_name WHRE trim(col_name) in (null, '', <your other values>);
```

**Edit:**

For integer type column the empty valuea will be **NULL** only, OR you can also treat `0` as empty value:

```
SELECT * FROM table_name WHRE col_name in (null, 0, <your other values>);
```

Comment: @HarishAravind, `null` can be store in integer column type in MySQL, Oracle, and SQL Server. But not for the field in which you set 'NOT NULL' constraints OR primary key constraints. | if want to pass empty-value-to-integer-column then you should set `Year` column as nullable OR pass `0` in place of empty value.

Comment: @HarishAravind :- You can set `0` or `''` as default value for your dropdowns. IN HTML: `<select><option value='0'></option> ...your-other-option-items...</select>` **OR** `<select><option value=''>- Select Program -</option> ...your-other-option-items...</select>`. **|** If you are working on .Net/Windows application, there are also similer option to return default value if user ignores that dropdown(may be at coding level), check for those.

Comment: I will try these options :) Thanks

Answer (score 1):

From what you posted I'm guessing you have a problem defining the blank value.

```
SELECT * FROM table
WHERE col_name IS NULL OR
      col_name IN (<list_of_your_values>, '', 0,)
```